# Updating a variable value when Leaflet popup is clicked in svelte

Tags: javascript, leaflet, svelte

I have url inside the popup of the Leaflet map. I want to set a variable value when this link is clicked.
Below is the code. I am reading values of plotArray and adding it to leaflet map. When clicked on "Click here for details" it will direct to the other component "Details".
The problem is, when i click on the url it is not setting the value.

```
for (var b = 0; b < plotArray.length; b++) {
  //For each entry of plotArray, add it to the map
  let ColMark;
  let content = L.DomUtil.create("div", "myPopup");
  content.innerHTML = `X: ${plotArray[b].X}, Y: ${plotArray[b].Y}, ID:${plotArray[b].id16}
      <br> <a style="font-size: small" href="/Details">Click here for details</a>`;
  if (plotArray[b].Mode == "Anchor") {
    ColMark = greenIcon;
  } else {
    ColMark = orangeIcon;
  }
  L.marker([plotArray[b].X, plotArray[b].Y], { icon: ColMark })
    .addTo(layerGroup)
    .bindPopup(content)
    .openPopup();
  content.onclick = (e) => {
    SelectedID.set(plotArray.id16); //i want to set value of the SelectID to the ID available inside content meaning whichever the popup is selected
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/Details", { replace: true });
  };
}
```

[image: this is how the popup looks]

With respect to the image when the url inside the popup is clicked, SelectedID value should be set to 0x3f1a.

How can i do this ?

Comment: And how is `SelectedID` being defined? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is a writable variable which i have defined in store.js and imported in this component, I want to update this variable in this component so that i can use this value in Details component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. `SelectedID.set(plotArray.id16);` will never work because the index is missing, it should be `SelectedID.set(plotArray[b].id16);`
2. The click listener on the content element will only work for the last popup in the array. Because you have multiple popups each will be opened and the click listener applied but then it will be removed from the DOM because you open another popup. So only the last popup will have the listener.
3. I'm not sure if `SelectedID.set(plotArray.id16);` will take every time the right id, because you are in a loop and appling the click listener.

So change your code to following:

```
for (var b = 0; b < plotArray.length; b++) {
      //For each entry of plotArray, add it to the map
      let ColMark;
      let content = L.DomUtil.create("div", "myPopup");
      content.innerHTML = `X: ${plotArray[b].X}, Y: ${plotArray[b].Y}, ID:${plotArray[b].id16}
      <br> <a style="font-size: small" href="/Details">Click here for details</a>`;
      if (plotArray[b].Mode == "Anchor") {
          ColMark = greenIcon;
      } else {
          ColMark = orangeIcon;
      }
      
      // In this listener we read out the current marker of the popup and get the id to create a click listener on the content.
      map.on('popupopen',(e)=>{
          var marker = e.popup._source;
          var id = marker.plotId;
          e.popup._content.onclick = (e) => {
              alert(id);
              /*
              SelectedID.set(id); //i want to set value of the SelectID to the ID available inside content meaning whichever the popup is selected
              e.preventDefault();
              navigate("/Details", { replace: true });
               */
          };
      });

      var marker = L.marker([plotArray[b].X, plotArray[b].Y], { icon: ColMark })
          .addTo(layerGroup)
          .bindPopup(content);
      // the id is now a property of the marker and can read out over the marker
      marker.plotId = plotArray[b].id16;
      // open the popup after .plotId is set, because else plotId is undefined in `popupopen` event
      marker.openPopup();
  }
```